# Google Chrome Developer tools -CSS file is shown empty

Tags: css, html, google-chrome-devtools

Thankyou for your precious time;
i'm a beginner in web development and as i was trying my hands on html and css 
i found that the css styling isn't getting applied to the html and that the chrome 
developer tools shows it to be empty (the file is present but the code that i've written in css file seems to be absent) 
please help!

[image: Screenshot of the problem.]

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MY WEB PAGE </title>
  <link type="text/css" href="style.css"  rel="stylesheet" >
</head>
  <body>
  <h1>THIS IS MY WEB PAGE </h1>
    <p>
    css applied to this part of the code isnt being shown in the developers
    tools
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css file

```
body{
  background-color:black;;
}
h1{
  color:white;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
p{
  font-family: serif;
  color:yellow;
  font-style: oblique;
}
```

Comment: Check your web server configuration and the CSS file itself in file manager.

Comment: Silly things to check: Have you ensured you saved the CSS file in your editor? Are you sure the file is in the correct location? In the file manager, if you open the CSS file, is it blank?

Comment: i've used the http-server ,and yes the file is saved in the editor and the location is right

Comment: So you are able to access http://your-server.com/style.css?

Comment: Resave the CSS file in UTF8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing an angle bracket on your first line or it could be a copy-paste error.  It should be: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Also look in the Network tab in Chrome toolbar to make sure that it's able to find your style.css and it contains the right CSS.

Depending on how it's being hosted, you may have to hit Ctrl-F5 to tell the browser to download everything fresh instead of caching.

Comment: it's a copy paste error and i've tired refreshing too

Comment: What does the network tab show in Chrome toolbar?  Are you getting a 200 on style.css?

Answer (score 0):

Clear the browser cache. It happens sometimes.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Answer (score -2):

you have to save css and html file in a same folder as your writed

Comment: they're saved in the same folder